# Unable to pass the command "airflow db init"

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am new to Python as well Apache Airflow. By going thru the documentation I am trying to open Airflow GUI as par of this process I am passing the comment "airflow db inint". However, I getting the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k0rR.png)

I went thru the Airflow documentation, but I'm unable to figure out the solutions.